# JS/Ajax: grab input field value without refresh or button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently using js function to submit data without page refresh or button click. The input field is inside  tab #2 that executes the js once the user stops typing. The problem is that the js is making the page refresh thus taking me back to tab#1. How can I prevent the page from refreshing? I thought i had included the necessary code in the JS function to stop this. [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/TabsNextPrev/index.php)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
        $('#video-input1').on('keyup', function() {
            var value = this.value;

            clearTimeout(timer);

            timer = setTimeout(function() {

                //do your submit here
                $("#ytVideo").submit()


                //alert('submitted:' + value);
            }, 2000);
        });

    //submit definition once submit is executed
    $('#ytVideo').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh
        var form = $('#ytVideo').serialize();

        //submit.php is the page where you submit your form
        $.post('index.php#tab-2', form, function(data){ 
            var x = $(data);
            $("body").html(x);
        });
        return false;
    });
    return false;                                                         

});
</script>
```

Comment: The `$("#ytVideo").submit()` line is the problem. Your submitting the form, before it gets to your `$('#ytVideo').submit(function(e){` event where you disable the default behavior and return false.

Comment: Thank you for responding, how could i fix such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this line

```
//do your submit here
$("#ytVideo").submit()
```

to

```
$("#ytVideo").trigger("submit");
```

i believe the problem is that you define what submit should do after the form has been submitted this causes the page to reload.
*Edited*
try this change

```
$('#ytVideo').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh
        event.stopPropagation(); //+
        var form = $('#ytVideo').serialize();

        //submit.php is the page where you submit your form
        $.post('index.php#tab-2', form, function(data){ 
            var x = $(data);
            $("body").html(x);
        });
        //- return false;
    });
    //- return false;
```

made some changes

Comment: +1 Yes, I did what you said but it seems to refresh the page taking me back to tab-1

Comment: made some changes, also you make $("body").html(x) <- this replaces all body HTML, hope that script tag with jquery code isn't in there because it will be replaced!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.submit()` you should use `.triggerHandler('submit')`. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) and [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772537/triggerhandler-vs-trigger-in-jquery).