# Why jQuery triggerHandler() works but trigger() doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-trigger, jquery-triggerhandler

Click an element using [`triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler) works:

```
$element = $('#gwt-debug-location-pill-edit-div:visible');
$element.triggerHandler('click');
```

But, clicking it using [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger), doesn't:

```
$element.trigger('click');
```

Why is that?

---

To replicate this (in Firefox and Chrome):

- Go to https://adwords.google.com/select/home, and log in using your credentials
- Tools and Analysis `->` Keyword Planner
- Expand "Enter or upload keywords to see how they perform"
- Using browser's console, try to click on the locations box (marked in red in the screenshot below) via the two methods above (you'll need to inject jQuery into the page. I used [jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet) to do that.)

---

[image]

Comment: Think this answers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772537/triggerhandler-vs-trigger-in-jquery

Comment: Could you pinpoint the exact reason?

Comment: The .triggerHandler() method does not cause the default behavior of an event to occur. else everything is almost same..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's compare [`jQuery.fn.trigger` and `jQuery.fn.triggerHandler`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L818):

```
trigger: function( type, data ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery.event.trigger( type, data, this );
    });
},
triggerHandler: function( type, data ) {
    var elem = this[0];
    if ( elem ) {
        return jQuery.event.trigger( type, data, elem, true );
    }
}
```

The only real difference is the fourth argument, `true`, given to `jQuery.event.trigger` with `triggerHandler`.

Looking at `jQuery.event.trigger`, [the argument is called `onlyHandlers`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L209), and among other things, [the documentation of `triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) notes that:

> - The .triggerHandler() method does not cause the default behavior of an event to occur (such as a form submission).

We can see [where the default behaviour is actually triggered](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L307):

```
// If nobody prevented the default action, do it now
if ( !onlyHandlers && !event.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
```

In the case that `onlyHandlers` is false (`trigger()`), and no event handler stopped the default event from executing, the default action will then be executed.

With `onlyHandlers` being true (`triggerHandler()`), this will never happen.

So, for the `trigger()` case, it ends up executing `click()` on the target element, which triggers the state change correctly—but it turns out that, in both the `trigger()` and `triggerHandler()` cases, the click was **already** correctly fired up in [the loop through the eventPath above](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L300):

```
// Native handler
handle = ontype && cur[ ontype ];
if ( handle && jQuery.acceptData( cur ) && handle.apply && handle.apply( cur, data ) === false ) {
```

So `trigger('click')` ends up clicking the element twice (!) — presumably because `click()` doesn't return false, so the event default action is never prevented — whereas `triggerHandler('click')` only does it once.

This can be verified by stepping through the `jQuery.event.trigger` method with the inspector and seeing the selector open, then close again.

The question is if this what we should generally expect; it seems strange that an otherwise-working event trigger would cause double triggers in the case of a DOM-only reaction.