# JQuery trigger event performance on document

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, events

I'm building a publish/subscribe framework in jQuery and I'm wondering if there are performance penalties to triggering and listening to events on the document root?

All articles I can find describe the penalty you obviously get for listening to events on the document level, but triggering them from a more specific element - listening for a "click" for example.

My pseudo code:

```
$(document).on("myCustomEvent", function() {
    alert("Event triggered");
});
$(document).trigger("myCustomEvent");
```

My event does not have a fitting home in the DOM but I could always add a dummy element to trigger from/listen to if it's better, but would rather not. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) propagates up the DOM.  It also interacts with all elements matching the object, which can cause conflicts / unexpected behavior.  Neither of these are inherent* performance hits -- and since you're using a custom event, you shouldn't have an issue with other elements matching the object.  That's really only a problem when trigger() is used with a real event, like trigger('click').
If you're concerned about either of these (bubbling up the DOM or other matching elements), you can use [triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772537/triggerhandler-vs-trigger-in-jquery) goes into more detail about the differences between trigger() and triggerHandler()

Comment: how about namespacing his events too? -> $(..).trigger("ns.click")